# load external json data file in to chartjs in the angular component

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

i am beginner in angular and chartjs. I want to load same data file in different chart. so i create a json file. and i want to load it my chart.

My code is like below

**external_data.json**

```
[{
    "data": "[13, 22, 30, 40, 50]",
    "label": "Africa",
    "borderColor": "#3e95cd",
    "fill": "false"
}, {
    "data": "[47, 14, 37, 67, 80]",
    "label": "Asia",
    "borderColor": "#8e5ea2",
    "fill": "false"
}]
```

**line-chart.component.ts**

```
       var ctx = document.getElementById("line-chart");

    new Chart(ctx, {


        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [1850, 1900, 1950, 2000, 2050],

           datasets:  // i want get json here

        }

    });
```

[this is folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGtrw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juse mention the path as follows,

```
loaddata() {
   this.Items = this.http.get("../data/external_data.json")
                 .map(res => res.json());
 }
```

and assign this.Items to your array

Comment: get some error like that
[ts] Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'

Comment: you need to import import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

Comment: its ok.. but now get this
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: import http inside your constructor